# Message Semantics - Unity to ROS over ROSBridge

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosbridge, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to exchange my message between windows 10 Unity 20.17.2 and ROS1. I can subscribe to my ros topic and I am able to listen to messages in my unity environment sent from ros1.

for subscribing I am sending:

```
`{"op": "subscribe", "topic": "/talker", "type": "std_msgs/String"}`
```

from windows to ros1 using ros_bridge websockets.

However, when I publish I cannot see my message on my ros terminal.
I advertise first:

```
{"op": "advertise", "topic": "/talker", "type": "std_msgs/String"}
```

which reflects over ros bridge as 1 client is connected.

Then I publish my message:

```
{"op": "publish", "topic": "/talker", "msg": {"data" : _my_message }}
```

My subscriber node: (just using straight away from the tutorial)

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "sub_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("talker", 0, chatterCallback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

But I never receive any message. I have converted my message into JSON as per rosbridge protocol:
`{ "op": "publish",(optional) "id": <string>,"topic": <string>, "msg": <json>}`

I am using the **websocketsharp library** to create my WebSocket connection, which should not really be an issue as I can listen to messages from ros and establish the connection. It should be something wrong with my publisher node or data model I am sending.

Any pointers, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283496/message-semantics---unity-to-ros-over-rosbridge/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I finally figured this out.
For publishing I had to enclose my string into another set of inverted comma send:

```
{"op": "publish", "topic": "/talker", "msg": {"data" : "_my_message " }}
```

basically, I used Wireshark to sniff the network, and checked my working ROS to Unity channel, and figured out what was missing on my Unity to ROS medium.

Also, I realized I was using Simple Json to convert my message to json which is not really important.

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2018-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0